# Linq query stored as string and/or serialized as Json

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.2

With a given list of objects, e.g.

```
public List<Event> itemList { get; set; }
```

I do like this to query it

```
var newItemList = itemList
                  .Where(l => l.Published && l.PublishStart <= DateTime.Today)
                  .OrderBy(l => l.PublishStart)
                  .ToList();
```

---

Now I need to be able to have multiple query's and started out with doing

```
List<Event> newItemList;

if (EventType.Equals("consert"))
{
    newItemList = itemList
                  .Where(l => l.Published && l.PublishType == EventType.Consert)
                  .OrderBy(l => l.PublishStart)
                  .ToList();
}
else if (EventType.Equals("last-chance"))
{
    newItemList = itemList
                  .Where(l => l.Published)
                  .OrderBy(l => l.PublishEnd)
                  .ToList();
}
// and so on...
```

*Do note, these samples is simplified/shortened*

---

As the above gets longer and longer, and to simplify the code a little, is it possible to store a query as string and/or serialized as Json, and do something like this ?

```
    var query_where = "l => l.Published && l.PublishType == EventType.Consert";
    var query_orderby = "l => l.PublishStart";

    newItemList = itemList
                  .Where(query_where)
                  .OrderBy(query_orderby)
                  .ToList();
```

---

As mentioned, I realize it might not be type-safe, still, I really need it stringified, or serialized, in one way or the other, so it can be dynamically added to the solution.

Comment: Even if it is possible, you will lose strong typing there. Will make it less maintainable.

Comment: @sateesh If I do, I do, still, want the option, and as you can see, the above `if..then..else` will be no easier to maintain when the query list expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using a nuget package [System.Dynamic.Linq.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)

```
    var where = "";
    var ordering = "";

    if (eventType.Equals("consert"))
    {
        where = "Published and PublishType =\"Consert\"";
        ordering = "PublishStart";

    }
    else if (eventType.Equals("last-chance"))
    {
        where = "Published";
        ordering = "PublishEnd";
    }

    newItemList = itemList.AsQueryable() // this is in order to enable Dynamic.Linq
        .Where(where)
        .OrderBy(ordering)
        .ToList();
```

But as others pointed, you might not need this, since the `IEnumerable` interface is composable, in the way that you can decide what put in the Where clauses without actually running them.

```
    IEnumerable<Event> newItems = itemList;

    if (eventType.Equals("consert"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.Where(c => c.Published && c.PublishType == EventType.Consert);
    }
    else if (eventType.Equals("last-chance"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.Where(c => c.Published);
    }


    if (eventType.Equals("consert"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.OrderBy(c => c.PublishStart);
    }
    else if (eventType.Equals("last-chance"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.OrderBy(c => c.PublishEnd);
    }

    var newItemsList = newItems.ToList(); // newItems holds references to the expressions and the .ToList() call will parse and execute them at this moment
```

This duplication might be annoying thus you have also the option to use `Func`.

```
    IEnumerable<Event> newItems = itemList;
    Func<Event, DateTime> orderBy = null;

    if (eventType.Equals("consert"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.Where(c => c.Published && c.PublishType == EventType.Consert);
        orderBy = c => c.PublishStart;

    }
    else if (eventType.Equals("last-chance"))
    {
        newItems = newItems.Where(c => c.Published);
        orderBy = c => c.PublishEnd;

    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        newItems = newItems.OrderBy(orderBy);
    }


    var newItemsList = newItems.ToList(); // newItems holds references to the expressions and the .ToList() call will parse and execute them at this moment
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with methods, for example:

```
private bool IsEventPublishedConcert(Event l) => l.Published && l.PublishType == EventType.Consert;
private DateTime GetEventStartTime(Event l) => l.StartTime;


newItemList = itemList
              .Where(IsEventPublishedConcert)
              .OrderBy(GetEventStartTime)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Please read the question again. They are asking for a way to serialize the predicate. building the predicate at run-time, not compile-time.

Comment: They are asking to simplify the code, and suggested a possible solution. However, working with strings is not type-safe, so I wouldn't go for that.

Comment: @Metheny Thanks for your answer. I realize it might not be type-safe, still, I really need it stringified, or serialized, in one way or the other. This will be a part of a CMS solution and we can't keep recompiling code every time a user need a different query. And the query is created by us, so we will know very clearly how-to.

Comment: @LGSon: I understand, but still. using code as configuration is rarely recommended. What you can do is create a modular structure for the query (i.e. query "building blocks"), possibly by using C# expressions, and allow configuration by the building blocks names. Then you can have a factory that creates the query from the building blocks by their name.